# MVVM Multitouch command binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, multi-touch, commandbinding

I would like to create a WPF dialog where the user has to press (at least) two buttons before a command is executed.
I am able to create this using code-behind (touch events), but prefer to use MVVM command binding and a dedicated user control so it can be reused in other applications.

How can I activate the ICommand when both buttons are pressed simultaneously?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with creating a user control that has this behaviour and using that throughout your app - why the need for MVVM ? When you've detected that 2 buttons have been pressed in your code-behind, you can raise a routed event.

Comment: Maybe in your VM you should have props that bound to IsPressed props of your buttons, then in your command check if they both pressed and execute

Comment: All my applications use the MVVM pattern where there is a clear separation between ViewModel and View(s). The views may differ, depending on different situations (e.g. a touch device is available).
So I do not want to have references to buttons but only interact using commands (ICommand).
E.g. on a non-touch device, the user could press a single button before the command is activated.

Comment: Supposed solution doesn't break MVVM pattern. You won't have references to buttons, instead you'll declare VM props that indicate special states (like you do with check boxes or toggle buttons). And in your command (or CanExecute method) check if touch device is available so you can make it behave as you want.

Comment: Another clue is that in MVVM you can actually use code behind as long as it doesn't mess with model, validation or any other logic except view logic itself. So you can have button click handler in your code behind that check pressed states of buttons and executes your VM method. Of course it can be easy-difficult-impossible to do depending on youe particular VM - View implementation and style.

Comment: Thank you Den & auburg,
I will try to develop a reusable User Control/Code Behind where a user of that control can add any number of (toggle) buttons that must be pressed simultaneously using a touch screen or must be IsPressed before a routed event is raised.